# Solution of an undetermined linear system under a constrain on the norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an equation of the kind:
$$\|\overrightarrow{y}-\hat{A}\overrightarrow{x}\|_2\lt\epsilon$$ in which the matrix $\hat{A}$ is given and is a matrix $N \times M$ with the number of columns greather than the number of rows. The vector $\overrightarrow{y}$ is also given $(N \times 1)$, find the vector $\overrightarrow{x}$ satisfying the previous equation with $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\|.\|_2$ the norm $2$ of the vector.

Comment: Is this really the problem you want to solve? This can be seen as the ordinary least-squares problem with its solvability depending on whether or not the least-squares residual is small enough. Also, if the solution exists, it's obviously not unique.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: really, the matrix $\hat{A}$ is ill - conditioned

Comment: OK, but this does not change anything on the basic approach (except that you probably want to use a numerically stable least-squares solver). Does the matrix have other interesting properties (e.g., is it sparse)?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: the matrix is ill conditioned, but it doesn't have other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the system $Ax=y$ is consistent ($y\in\mathcal{R}(A)$), then for some solution $x$ we have $\|y-Ax\|_2=0<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

On the other hand, if $y\not\in\mathcal{R}(A)$, then $x=A^{\dagger}y$ (where $A^{\dagger}$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$) is the/a least-squares solution of $Ax\approx y$, that is,
$$
\|y-AA^{\dagger}y\|_2=\min_{x}\|y-Ax\|_2.
$$
In addition, among all least-squares solutions, $A^{\dagger}y$ has the minimal 2-norm. If $\|y-AA^{\dagger}y\|_2$ is smaller than the given (positive) $\epsilon$, then it can be considered as *a* solution to the given problem.

Note that the solution (if it exists) is not unique due to the continuity of the norm.